# Restrict allowed methods on Traefik routes

Tags: http, kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm currently using traefik 1.6.x as ingress controller in my K8s clusters. I wanted to update to 1.7.x (and then to 2.x later on), but my ingresses are not working anymore after the update.

The issue seems to be, that I do http method restrictions on my ingresses by adding the methods to the `traefik.frontend.rule.type` annotation as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-name
  namespace: namespace1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: "Method: CONNECT, DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT; PathPrefix"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts-max-age: "315360000"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts-include-subdomains: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-frame-options-value: "SAMEORIGIN"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/content-type-nosniff: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/browser-xss-filter: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: "Server:||X-Application-Context:||X-Powered-By:||exception:"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ...
```

I don't know if this was ever intended to be done in this way, but apparently it worked. I found that in some other StackOverflow post, iirc.

Removing the Method part (or the whole annotation then, because `PathPrefix` is the default) brings the routes back to life. But of course this allows the `TRACE` method again, for example.

Is there another way to restrict those (maybe even for all ingresses) with traefik versions from 1.7.x?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using [CORS headers](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/headers/#cors-headers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the comment of @Crou about CORS headers worked! I just now stumbled upon this problem again and moved the *method* part to the *custom-reponse-headers* and it seems to work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-name
  namespace: namespace1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts-max-age: "315360000"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts-include-subdomains: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-frame-options-value: "SAMEORIGIN"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/content-type-nosniff: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/browser-xss-filter: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: "Server:||X-Application-Context:||X-Powered-By:||exception:||Access-Control-Allow-Headers:CONNECT, DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ...
```

I removed the `traefik.frontend.rule.type` part then completely, since `PathPrefix` is the default.

(!) I only moved up to traefik 1.7.20. I've not managed to do the migration to traefik 2 yet. So I'm not sure if this works with traefik 2!

Comment: That `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:GET` should be `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET`, right ? And this would not block the requests with an incorrect HTTP method.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That is a typo there. it should be `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. This does not fix the underlying problem though, as those headers are mainly used by browsers. So you're not really blocking the requests.

We moved to Traefik2 in the meantime and configured allowed Methods in the ingress rules.