# Traefik as ingress controller - match HTTP method

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

For Traefik 1.7 as an ingress controller, how to match HTTP Method to route to a specific service?

For example, I want to pass a request to the service, only if HTTP method is GET and it matches with provided path.

I am looking documentation at: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/

But cannot find any relevant annotation. Is there any possible workaround?

[I found a similar question: [Restrict allowed methods on Traefik routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012063/restrict-allowed-methods-on-traefik-routes)  but answered to handle CORS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that was not a feature of 1.7.

Comment: do you know any new release of traefik has this capability?

Comment: Traefik 2.0+ supports this via `Method("GET")` in the routing rule, but you have to use their custom IngressRoute type rather than the standard Ingress.